# Installing ubuntu in free space of extended partition: "You have not selected any partitions for use as swap space"

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, swap, partitioning

Here is a picture of my hdd's partition table :

[image]

I wish to install Ubuntu in the free space shown in the below picture. However I don't understand how to configure the installation. I chose the `something else` option at the installation menu, after which the `installation type` window was displayed. I selected the free space and pressed the `+` button beside the `Change...`. Then a window popped up :

[image]

I want to use the entire space for my ubuntu installation hence didn't make any changes in the size. Didn't understand the `Use as:` drop down so I let that be. The only change I made was selecting `\` in the mount point. Then clicked `OK` and `Install`. Then this box popped up :

[image]

I didn't understand what to do next, so I quit. Please tell me what options I need to select to install Ubuntu in that 100Gb(93.14Gb) of free space. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installer is warning you that you have not created or configured a swap partition. On low memory systems, having a swap partition can increase performance by making more physical memory available, because the system can write out allocated but unused memory pages to disk.

If you have a large amount of physical memory (>8GB) then you probably do not need a swap space for a desktop system. If you have low memory (<2GB) then you might want to enable swap.

If you do decide to enable swap, you will need to create an extra partition of the appropriate size, and in the "Use as" drop down select "Swap".

Also see:

- [Ubuntu Swap FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)
- [Why is swap being used even though I have plenty of free RAM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157793/why-is-swap-being-used-even-though-i-have-plenty-of-free-ram)
- [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap)
- [Do we still need swap partitions on desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291378/do-we-still-need-swap-partitions-on-desktop)

Comment: This is odd. The last time I installed ubuntu on my machine it didn't ask for memory for swap space.

Comment: Perhaps you already had a swap partition on the disk? If Ubuntu finds one, it will just use it without asking.

Answer (score 2):

You did everything right. The last warning could have been ignored if you have more than 4GB of RAM. Except for the disk selection window (where you can erase data by doing something wrong) everything else could be "Next-Next-Next-Finish"

Comment: This is odd. The last time I installed ubuntu on my machine it didn't ask for memory for swap space.

Comment: Seems that you had swap partition on the disk already. Otherwise it asks for swap without checking RAM size.

Comment: The last time I created a 100 Gb memory space from the C drive. Which after a complete format of my harddisk turned out as this 100 Gb of free space that I can't seem to merge back. Should a swap space of 4GB be enough given that I have 4GB of RAM ?

Comment: The amount of swap is a holywar-igniting question. I think there is no reason to have space more than your RAM + 200Mb, and this is only needed for hibernation functionality.